# Selenium C#: Get Element by title

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get an element by its title, I don't know if we have a universal solution for this in Selenium C#.
Here is the example of the HTML

```
   <div class="student">
     <a href="abcxyz.com">
        <span class="title"> ZZZ</span>
     </a>
   </div>
```

And another example

```
   <div class="page">
      <a href="asdf.com" class="button-1" title="ZZZ"> </a>
   </div>
```

Of course if just one page, I will do it like

```
   FindElement(By.ClassName("page")).GetAttribute("href");
```

or

```
    FindElement(By.ClassName("student")).GetAttribute("href")
```

to get the "href" out of where the "title" is located. But they have pages with different designs, and the only common thing between them is that title. I wonder if there is any solution for me to find the "href" by the "title=ZZZ"?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The two examples are different, I would use a union (|) operator of XPath expressions that will work in both cases. If you have more cases, you can add additional union operator, followed by the new case XPath:

```
//a[@title='ZZZ']/@href | //*[@class='title'][contains(text(),'ZZZ')]/parent::a/@href
```

Without searching for specific text:

```
//a[@title]/@href | //*[@class='title']/parent::a/@href
```

Comment: so, there is no way to search by just the "title" only?

Comment: Your "title" has different HTML representations, so I am not aware of such a way, different from the XPaths I have posted. In the first case, the title is the value of the class attribute, in the second the title is an attribute itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath:

```
/a[@title="ZZZ"]/@href
```